# UIImage becomes transparent around edges even with alpha equal to 1.0

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I'm trying to make a lottery scratch-off game and found some open-source code that I could use. However, it's not very well done and I'm not sure how to fix it. The major problem is that the image you set as the scratch-off surface becomes partly transparent around the top and bottom edges (this seems to happen randomly, but about 90% of the time). The image is also flipped upside-down and inverted, as if looking into a mirror.

In the image below, the circle to the right is a normal imageView with the correct image (it looks flipped around because, rather than find the code that flipped the image, I simply decided to edit my image so when it was flipped around it looked normal). The image to the right is the scratch-off. It's appearance is created, I believe, through this method:

```
- (void)initContextWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    int width       = self.frame.size.width;
    int height      = self.frame.size.height;
    self.opaque     = NO;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    CFMutableDataRef pixels = CFDataCreateMutable( NULL , width * height );
    alphaPixels = CGBitmapContextCreate( CFDataGetMutableBytePtr( pixels ) , width , height , 8 , width , colorspace , kCGImageAlphaNone );
    provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(pixels);
    CFRelease(pixels);

    // Create scratchable CGImageRef
    scratchable = [image CGImage];

    // Set up CGContext for real
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(alphaPixels, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(alphaPixels, self.frame);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(alphaPixels, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(alphaPixels, lineWidth);
    CGContextSetLineCap(alphaPixels, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(width, height, 8, 8, width, provider, nil, NO);
    scratched = CGImageCreateWithMask(scratchable, mask);

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

    _promptView = nil;
    _touched = NO;
}
```

Is there any way I can fix this transparency issue?

[image]

Comment: Where else is self.opaque being used?

Comment: Literally nowhere else in the project. That is the one mention of the word "opaque."

Comment: Well if that's the case I'd remove it just to avoid future confusion! I was hoping it would be an easy fix for you :/

Comment: When I remove it, this is what becomes of the `View`: [link](http://i.imgur.com/671n9Lq.png). And it no longer disappears when you "scratch" it.

Comment: Huh. Well that's not what I was expecting. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with a lot of these function calls so I don't know if I can help that much

Comment: Well thank you tons for your effort.

Comment: Can you see what commenting out the three lines starting with CGContextSetStrokeColor... ... [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor); does? It looks to me like that might be creating the scratched look of the second image. However I'm also wondering if the issue is outside this function if it only happens some of the time

Comment: It happens according to the size of the image. If the image is less than about 125 by 125, it is not see-through. If it is greater, it looks like the above.

As for those three lines, commenting out the top one made it so when you "scratch" the image, it doesn't become see-through. The second one sets the line width of your scratch, and the third--I'm not 100% sure.